# Scraping ASPx page with no form data

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

everyone, I want to scrape [this aspx site](https://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/spmf_slc/InformaSQL.aspx) but couldn't find anyway of doing it, I don't find many examples online on how to scrape aspx sites... I tried following [this tutorial](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition) but the site doesn't seem to pass any form data field, only a view state. [Form data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZoS1.png)

To reach the information you enter a code in the first field and click "Incluir", then you click "Continuar" to view the information.
codes are like these: 001.003.0001-4 or 001.003.0002-2.
You get redirected to [this page](https://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/spmf_slc/ConsultaPreliminar.aspx) where a table with the information is shown.

I've also tried decoding the viewstate from string 64, but it only shows gibberish.

Can anyone please point me to a direction to achieving this, or tell me if it is impossible to scrape at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you'll find a working script for a **SINGLE** number. I used `start_urls` to get cookies **BEFORE** the very first POST (maybe you don't need them).

You can use this code as a starting point to working with several numbers at a single time or perform a search one by one.

```
import scrapy
import re

class PrefeituraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "prefeitura"
    start_urls = ['https://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/spmf_slc/InformaSQL.aspx']
    numbers = [
        '001.003.0001-4',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for number in self.numbers:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response=response,
                formdata={
                    'ctl00$rsAjaxManager': 'ctl00$rsAjaxManager|ctl00$pnlConteudo$btnAdicionarSQL',
                    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
                    'PageProdamSPOnChange': number,
                    'PageProdamSPPosicao': 'Form=0;0/',
                    'PageProdamSPFocado': 'ctl00_pnlConteudo_btnAdicionarSQL',
                    'ctl00$pnlConteudo$txtSQL': number,
                    '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
                    'ctl00$pnlConteudo$btnAdicionarSQL': 'Incluir',
                },
                headers={
                    'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
                },
                callback=self.press_continue,
                # meta={
                #     'cookiejar': number,
                # }
            )

    def press_continue(self, response):
        """ We need to parse response MANUALLY (using re.search()) because ALL ASPX magical values (__VIEWSTATE etc)
            are included using special format (pipe separator). Next we need to construct a FormRequest manually (without
            .from_response()) too because there is no <form> in response.
        """
        # with open("Samples/Add.htm", "wb") as f:
        #     f.write(response.body)

        view_state = re.search(r'__VIEWSTATE\|([^\|]+)', response.text).group(1)
        event_validation = re.search(r'__EVENTVALIDATION\|([^\|]+)', response.text).group(1)
        view_state_generator = re.search(r'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\|([^\|]+)', response.text).group(1)
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            method="POST",
            url="https://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/spmf_slc/InformaSQL.aspx",
            formdata={
                'PageProdamSPOnChange': '',
                'PageProdamSPPosicao': 'Form=0;0/',
                'PageProdamSPFocado': 'ctl00_pnlConteudo_BotoesContinuarVoltarSair1_btnContinuar',
                'ctl00$pnlConteudo$txtSQL': '',
                'ctl00$pnlConteudo$BotoesContinuarVoltarSair1$btnContinuar': 'Continuar',
                'ctl00$hidAbreFichaTecnicaItens': '',
                'ctl00$hidAbreAlvaraConstrucaoItens': '',
                'ctl00$hidMenuFichaTecnica': '0',
                'ctl00$hidMenuConsultaPreliminar': '0',
                'ctl00$hidMenuAlvaraConstrucao': '0',
                'ctl00$hidMenuGeral': '0',
                'ctl00$hdnAjaxScript': '',
                '__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': view_state_generator,
                '__EVENTTARGET': '',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation,
                '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            },
            headers={
                'referer': "https://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/spmf_slc/InformaSQL.aspx",
            },
            callback=self.parse_number,
        )

    def parse_number(self, response):
        with open("Samples/Number.htm", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time, with your code I was able to understand how it works and to scrape another similar [page](http://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cit/Forms/frmPesquisaGeral.aspx). In your code I tried to loop through a list of numbers, but the result only returns the last one in the list, do you know why that happen?

Comment: I believe that you need to use separate `cookiejar` for each number.